# rspec-1.3.2 fails with wrong number of arguments with Rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using rvm with ree-1.8.7-2011.03 and rspec-1.3.2, getting an error trying to run a spec file with Rails 2.3.14

Any help is appreciated since I can't run any spec tests. Thanks!

Running the spec file from my Rails folder like:
spec spec/models/assignment_spec.rb

~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:247:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)

```
from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:247:in `new'
from ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:247:in `load_formatters'
```

...

~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/.rb:

...

```
 def load_formatters(format_options, formatters)
    format_options.map do |format, where|
      formatter_type = if formatters[format]
        require formatters[format][0]
        eval(formatters[format][1], binding, __FILE__, __LINE__)
      else
        load_class(format, 'formatter', '--format')
      end

      formatter_type.new(formatter_options) # <-- 247
    end
  end

  def formatter_options
    @formatter_options ||= OpenStruct.new(
      :colour   => colour,
      :autospec => autospec,
      :dry_run  => dry_run
    )
  end
```

...

EDIT:

spec_helper.rb:
https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/stable/spec/spec_helper.rb

./.spec.opts:

--colour

--require spec/nested_instafail_formatter

--format RSpec::NestedInstafailFormatter

--format html:tmp/spec_html/index.html

Comment: Please show your spec_helper.rb

Comment: have you tried with `ree-1.8.7-2012.02` ?

Comment: Also please show the contents of `./spec.opts`

Comment: Added spec_helper.rb and ./spec.opts above.  Installed with ree-1.8.7-2012.02 and that seems to have done the trick, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"have you tried with ree-1.8.7-2012.02 ?" – mpapis yesterday

Mpapis answered this question, the spec test ran using ree-1.8.7-2012.02 with rspec-1.3.2,.